# add_post_meta prints out '6' on my page

Tags: wordpress

What I am trying to do is each time a logged in user opens single.php I log a post meta activity. Essentially I want to know every time a logged in user reads a post. So I put this in single.php inside the loop and after having checked if user is logged in.

First I got just '6' (which is the post ID) in my post, so I added some echo to find which function was doing that and this is what resulted.

```
echo "before post meta<br />";
add_post_meta( the_ID(), 'post_read', (string)$current_user->ID );
echo "after post meta<br />";
```

prints out in my post:

```
before post meta
6after post meta
```

Why is add_post_meta printing '6' (the post ID)? How can I get rid of it? An incidentally when I:

```
$post_reads = get_post_custom_values('post_read', the_ID());
```

All I get is '6' again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`the_ID`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID) is printing out the post ID. Use [`get_the_ID`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) to return it without printing.

Answer (score 1):

You are using [`the_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID) in your function call.  `the_ID()` *displays* the id to screen.  You want to use [`get_the_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) instead.  This will give you a usable ID you can use for your function call.